# UIStoryboard: What's the Correct Way to Get the Active Storyboard?

Tags: ios, runtime, storyboard

I am currently furiously digging through all the docs, and haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I suspect it is a real d'oh! answer.

I simply need to find the active storyboard in the main bundle, and want to know the best way to do this.

This is so that I can use the `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XXX" bundle:mainBundle]` to extract the running storyboard.

I know how to kludge it by switching on the idiom, but I feel that this is a...kludge.

What's a correct way of doing this?

Comment: That's the main storyboard, not the "active" storyboard, whatever that means. How many storyboards are in your app?

Comment: 2. One for iPhone, and one for iPad. This works fine. Only one is active at a time.

Comment: Oh right, I get you. You should add your code as an answer, then.

Comment: I'm too new. I'll add it later, when SO lets me, so I edited the original.

Comment: An easier way, if you are trying to get this from an existing view controller that was loaded from the storyboard (very common) is simply: `self.storyboard`

Comment: Thanks! In this case, that may be more appropriate.

Comment: Your answer pushed me in the right direction :) the code I'm using now is `UIStoryboard *sb = [[self.window rootViewController] storyboard];`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK. As my comment above indicates, I found the answer to the (badly phrased question):

I wanted to be able to get the **main** (not *active*) storyboard, as I'm not using multiple storyboards per incarnation. I'm using the standard model of 1 storyboard for iPhone, and 1 for iPad. I just wanted the cleanest way to get the storyboard, so that I could use it to generate a view controller.

I found the answer in [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code), and implemented it with the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: calling `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:...` creates a new instance of the storyboard. This won't give you access to the same instances that are actually loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, but that's OK. I want a new instance. The already loaded one is off doing something else.

Comment: Definitely the best answer for my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Or may be adding this to the AppDelegate as a Class method, so you can reuse the storyboard and avoid creating unnecessary instances.

Comment: Yeah...not a big deal to do that. But why bother, if it is only gonna be used once? Was that REALLY worth a downvote?

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez Good point, I've done this to avoid creating additional instances. Create storyboard once in ``application:DidFinishLaunching... `` or hold onto a ``vc.storyboard`` that was already created by system

Answer (score 41):

In case you want to get the active storyboard for a viewController, there's a storyboard property. This is how I solved it, instead of making a new instance:

```
LoginViewController *vc = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstLaunch"];
[navController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

In Swift you'd call:

```
let loginViewController = navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstLaunch") as! LoginViewController
navigationController?.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You could also be a lot safer by using guards against the navigation controller and the storyboard. I've used `as!` so as to guarantee that you're getting a LoginController.

Comment: +1 for the .storyboard property. This property is not only available for a navigation controller but also for UITableViewController, UITabBarController, UICollectionViewController, etc.

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift**, you'd use the following syntax:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Note that passing `nil` to `bundle` will make the call refer to your *main* bundle automatically.

If you're in a **view controller** that you have on the Storyboard and want to instantiate the Storyboard from there directly, you can just do:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard? = self.storyboard // call this inside a VC that is on the Storyboard
```

Note that in the last case, `self.storyboard` will return an *optional* Storyboard (`Storyboard?`), so if you'd like to use it unwrap it like so:

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
  // access storyboard here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better approach would be to get existing storyboard instance from `window's rootViewController` if not available then create a new instance.

```
let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard ?? UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Also using globally accessible helper functions like these can be a good idea provided that you pass the already active storyboard as parameter.

```
class Helper {
    static func getLoginVC(storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> LoginVC {
         return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: LoginVC.self)) as! LoginVC
    }
}
```

you can pass the active storyboard instance from a controller like this -

```
let loginVC = Helper.getLoginVC(storyboard: self.storyboard)
```

In case you are trying to access storyboard from appDelegate or sceneDelegate you can use -

```
let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard ?? UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginVC = Helper.getLoginVC(storyboard: storyboard)

let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: loginVC)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just copy pasted the code form above updated question so that everyone can see it as an answer.

```
UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```